# Pytorch: smarter way to reduce dimension by reshape

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

I want to reshape a Tensor by multiplying the shape of first two dimensions.

For example,

1st_tensor: `torch.Size([12, 10])` to `torch.Size([120])`

2nd_tensor: `torch.Size([12, 10, 5, 4])` to `torch.Size([120, 5, 4])`

I.e. The first two dimensions shall be merged into one, while the other dimensions shall remain the same.

Is there a smarter way than

`1st_tensor.reshape(-1,)`

`2nd_tensor.reshape(-1,5,4)`,

that can adapt to the shape of different Tensors?

---

Test cases:

```py
import torch
tests = [
    torch.rand(11, 11), 
    torch.rand(12, 15351, 6, 4),
    torch.rand(13, 65000, 8)
    ]
```

Comment: `t = t.reshape(-1, *t.shape[2:])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For tensor `t`, you can use:

```
t.reshape((-1,)+t.shape[2:])
```

This uses `-1` for flattening the first two dimensions, and then uses `t.shape[2:]` to keep the other dimensions identical to the original tensor.

For your examples:

```
>>> tests = [
...     torch.rand(11, 11),
...     torch.rand(12, 15351, 6, 4),
...     torch.rand(13, 65000, 8)
...     ]
>>> tests[0].reshape((-1,)+tests[0].shape[2:]).shape
torch.Size([121])
>>> tests[1].reshape((-1,)+tests[1].shape[2:]).shape
torch.Size([184212, 6, 4])
>>> tests[2].reshape((-1,)+tests[2].shape[2:]).shape
torch.Size([845000, 8])
```

Comment: I think this works without tuple() as well.

Comment: I think you may also need t.shape, otherwise looks good

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a better way I think:

```
import torch

tests = [
    torch.rand(11, 11), 
    torch.rand(12, 15351, 6, 4),
    torch.rand(13, 65000, 8)
    ]

for test in tests:
    print(test.flatten(0, 1).shape)
```

I'm not sure what version of torch this was added.